# Exclude duplicate records except for one different field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a list of transactions containing a customer number, date, amount and transaction type (buy or sell). I only want to return the transactions (per customer, per day, per amount) that are not cancelled out by the same customer, date and amount but with the opposite transaction type.

For example, my sample table (transactions) is below:

```
+----------+------------+--------+--------+
| Customer |    Date    | Amount | Action |
+----------+------------+--------+--------+
|     1111 | 15/09/2016 |      5 | Buy    |
|     2222 | 15/09/2016 |      5 | Sell   |
|     3333 | 15/09/2016 |      6 | Buy    |
|     3333 | 15/09/2016 |      6 | Sell   |
|     4444 | 15/09/2016 |      7 | Sell   |
|     2222 | 15/09/2016 |      6 | Buy    |
+----------+------------+--------+--------+
```

I only want the following items returned:

```
+----------+------------+--------+--------+
| Customer |    Date    | Amount | Action |
+----------+------------+--------+--------+
|     1111 | 15/09/2016 |      5 | Buy    |
|     2222 | 15/09/2016 |      5 | Sell   |
|     4444 | 15/09/2016 |      7 | Sell   |
|     2222 | 15/09/2016 |      6 | Buy    |
+----------+------------+--------+--------+
```

Customer 3333 has been left out because they had a buy and sell amount of the same value on the same day. Customer 2222 has been left in as even though they had a buy and sell on the same day, it was for different amounts so I need both records for them returned.

Comment: each customer will have only one sell and buy per date?

Comment: Yes. Each customer will have a max of only 1 buy and 1 sell per date. But some customer may only 1 action for the date e.g. 1111 and 4444 above have only 1 buy and 1 sell respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be enough:

```
SELECT Customer, Date, Amount, MAX(Action) Action
FROM Src
GROUP BY Customer, Date, Amount
HAVING COUNT(*)=1
```

**Test case**

```
WITH Src AS
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
    (1111, '15/09/2016', 5, 'Buy'),
    (2222, '15/09/2016', 5, 'Sell'),
    (3333, '15/09/2016', 6, 'Buy'),
    (3333, '15/09/2016', 6, 'Sell'),
    (4444, '15/09/2016', 7, 'Sell'),
    (2222, '15/09/2016', 6, 'Buy')
    ) T(Customer, Date, Amount, Action)
)
SELECT Customer, Date, Amount, MAX(Action) Action
FROM Src
GROUP BY Customer, Date, Amount
HAVING COUNT(*)=1
```

**Result**

```
Customer    Date       Amount      Action
----------- ---------- ----------- ----
1111        15/09/2016 5           Buy
2222        15/09/2016 5           Sell
2222        15/09/2016 6           Buy
4444        15/09/2016 7           Sell
```

Comment: That would include 3333 15/09/2016 6 Sell?

Comment: I misunderstood question. Updated.

Comment: Ah, clever!  I didn't think of that option and was struggling with a much more complex CTE approach.  Nice!